# MySQL Long Response Time

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-select-db

I have a valid MySQL Query that selects the latest occupancy percentage of a table from each community entered in my DB, but it seems to be scanning the entire DB of entries as the lookup time takes roughly 3-4 seconds.

With the details provided in the query below, can someone provide me with a faster/better way to lookup the latest timestamp field for each community? - I need the query to select every community entered, with the latest timestamp, but the limit for each community selected should be 1 (meaning community named "Test Community" will have possibly hundreds of submissions but I need the latest entered Timestamp selected, along with the same selection for every community entered in the table)

```
SELECT t1.reportID, t1.communityID, t1.region, t1.percentOccupied,  
t1.TIMESTAMP, Communities.fullName

FROM NightlyReports t1 

INNER JOIN Communities On t1.communityID = Communities.communityID

WHERE t1.TIMESTAMP = ( SELECT MAX( TIMESTAMP ) FROM NightlyReports WHERE 
t1.communityID = NightlyReports.communityID ) 

AND t1.region =  'GA' ORDER BY percentOccupied DESC
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my experience, correlated subqueries often have rather poor performance; try this instead:

```
SELECT t1.reportID, t1.communityID, t1.region, t1.percentOccupied
    , t1.TIMESTAMP, Communities.fullName
FROM NightlyReports AS t1 
INNER JOIN Communities ON t1.communityID = Communities.communityID
INNER JOIN (
   SELECT communityID, MAX( TIMESTAMP ) AS lastTimestamp
   FROM NightlyReports 
   WHERE region = 'GA'
   GROUP BY communityID
) AS lastReports ON t1.communityID = lastReports.communityID
                AND t1.TIMESTAMP = lastReports.lastTimestamp
WHERE t1.region =  'GA' 
ORDER BY percentOccupied DESC
```

Comment: Awesome, this query is exactly what I was looking for, this is why I love SO....thank you! Can you please describe the double INNER JOIN though? I have not messed with queries in a bit, but that is not something I have used before

Comment: You can join as many tables (or subqiueries) as needed (within sanity limits of course) as long as each has a unique identifier/alias. Nothing really special about multiple joins, just like a+b+c is isn't really any more special than a+b.

Comment: Ah okay that makes sense, I will remember for the future, thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Your query is fine.  For this query (which is rewritten just a bit):

```
SELECT nr.reportID, nr.communityID, nr.region, nr.percentOccupied,  
       nr.TIMESTAMP, c.fullName
FROM NightlyReports nr INNER JOIN
     Communities c
     ON nr.communityID = c.communityID
WHERE nr.TIMESTAMP = (SELECT MAX(nr2.TIMESTAMP)
                      FROM NightlyReports nr2
                      WHERE nr.communityID = nr2.communityID
                     ) AND
     nr.region =  'GA'
ORDER BY percentOccupied DESC;
```

You want indexes on:

- `NightlyReports(region, timestamp, communityid)`
- `NightlyReports(communityid, timestamp)`
- `Communities(communityID)`  (this may already exist)

The correlated subquery is not *per se* a problem.

Comment: Hmm... Looking back on this question, I'm curious. Are you saying that the alternative query you provided, with the correlated sub query still included, is just as fast as the answer by @Uueerdo? I will test this, but I'm curious because you mentioned that a sub query can be used a different way where it "is not per se a problem".

Comment: @ViaTech . . . Could be faster, especially with the given indexes.  I provided this answer because it is closer to your original query.